# getting {"code":"unauthorized","message":"unauthorized access"} after using "query" http api for InfluxDB 2.0

Tags: api, http, kubernetes, influxdb, influxdb-2

I am trying to contact influxdb running on kubernetes. I am new on influxdb and I have just started using it. I used the query http API in the following way: `curl "http://pod_ip_address/query?q=show+databases"` , but the response is `{"code":"unauthorized","message":"unauthorized access"}`. Now I have just the user UI, so maybe the problem could be related to that. Does anybody know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InfluxDB 2.0 requires authentication using an ORG and a Token. You can pass these as HTTP headers in your `curl` call as shown here: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/api-guide/api_intro/#authentication